# Make a wrapped property bindable

Tags: apache-flex, binding, flex4, properties

I have `Class1` with a read-only bindable property called `age`:

```
public class Class1 {
  private var _age:int;

  [Bindable(event="ageChanged"]
  public function get age():int {
    return this._age;
  }

  public function something():void {
    _age++;
    dispatchEvent(new Event("ageChanged"));
  }
}
```

I also have `Class2` which contains a private instance of `Class1`. And I want to make property `age` available from `Class1` and still be bindable.

```
public class Class2 {
  private var c1:Class1 = new Class1();

  [Bindable????]
  public function get age():int {
  }
}
```

Of course the `[Bindable]` tag there doesn't make sense. But how can I achieve the same effect?

I believe I can dispatch some sort of `ageChanged` event from `Class2` up to `Class1` and then have an event handler in `Class1` dispatch another local `ageChanged` event to which I bind `Class2`'s `age` property.

But this sounds unnecessarily complicated. Isn't there a simpler way? :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I've just put my composite class as public and access it from the view if it's a model (which i think it is).  If you don't want to do that, you can always use [BindingUtils](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/binding/utils/BindingUtils.html):

In the class 2 constructor

```
var watcher:ChangeWatcher = BindingUtils.bindProperty(this, 'age', c1, 'age');
```

Comment: Ah! Thanks @J_A_X ! That comes much closed to the magic I was looking for. This way the inner class doesn't have to explicitly communicate with the outside class through events. Thanks! Implemented and working fine. Actually this discussion was very useful, it made me more aware of BindingUtils which I tend to forget about since I do all my bindings in MXML.

Comment: making the inner class public is out of the question because the outer class is the one who deals with authentication. it would be a security breach :)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use something like:

```
public class Class2 extends EventDispatcher {
private var _c1:Class1;

public function set c1(value:Class1):void
{
  if (value == _c1)
    return;
  if (_c1)
    _c1.removeEventListener("ageChanged", ageChangedHandler);
  _c1 = value;
  if (_c1)
    _c1.addEventListener("ageChanged", ageChangedHandler);
}

private function ageChangedHandler(event:Event):void
{
  dispatchEvent(new Event("ageChanged"));
}

  [Bindable("ageChanged")]
  public function get age():int {
  }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping for a simpler magical solution where I could avoid the extra event. But... magic doesn't exist :) So I implemented what you suggested. Thanks ;)

Comment: Binding is all about events. If you won't generate events manually `mxmlc` compiler perform it in process of code generation. So there is no chance to avoid events dealing with binding.

Comment: Actually, J_A_X suggested down there and alternative which I like better since it doesn't require the inner class to explicitly send events to the outside. This way both classes communicate through pure binding mechanisms and don't need extra events. Thanks anyway!